# Python select data return boolean true-false and DELETE value true

Tags: python, mysql

**I made a program transaction.and if error,it should report position error. NOW I want to select value TRUE and DELETE value TRUE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="lll",user="ppp",passwd="ppp",db="ppp")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT(case when user1 = '1' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS IsEmtpy from dt")
print(cursor.fetchall())

try:

    if true:
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1='1'")
        print "DELETE SUCESS"
    else:
        print "DELETE ERROR"

        conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()
conn.close()
```

result :

```
File "./splinsert.py", line 13
    if true:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: First, You need to change true to True in try block.

Comment: I think, there will be tabs instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related to inconsistent indentation. Python relies on indentation to determine when "code blocks" start and stop. [Take a look at this for more details](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="lll",user="ppp",passwd="ppp",db="ppp")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT(case when user1 = '1' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS IsEmtpy from dt")
print(cursor.fetchall())

try:
  if True:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1='1'")
    print "DELETE SUCESS"
  else:
    print "DELETE ERROR"
    conn.commit()

except Exception as e:
  conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```